# What is cause for Eggplant leaves getting burn from edges in Summer?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, vegetables, bugs, eggplant

I have planted Eggplant in a Pot in winter. It has good growth now. Summer started and I found that Eggplant Leaves are getting brown from the edges & dying and no growth was found.

The Temperature is around ~40°C in Gujarat State in summer.

- Is the plant dying due to weather?
- Is there a solution to make plant make healthier this summer Season?
- Please provide some solution to make the plant growing again.

A few weeks ago there was some white fly seen, that time I had sprayed Neem oil with liquid soap mixture to get rid of thee bugs from the plant.

Few pictures:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar experience with this and mine was due to overfertilization. I used liquid fertilizer too frequently and the leaves of my potted eggplants started showing this. I limited my usage to just once per month and also decreased the amount and they disappeared. But since you saw insects in your area, you might want to find other causes as well. Happy planting!

Comment: Ok thanks. I have not over fertilizer, might be lower sunlight during the day. will try in next winter..  Happy planting..